# How to exclude jest/js test by tagName running with --testNamePattern?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have many tests written in Jest/JavaScript. These tests are in different files and some are marked with "@bug".

I want to skip running certain tests marked with "@bug".

For example, I want to exclude this test from running:

```
  test("@bug Sign In - Check Wrong user credentials: status-code 400", async () => {
        ...
      });
```

I tried run this script:

```
npx jest --testNamePattern='^(?!.*@bug).*$'
```

But it still ran all tests, including the ones marked with "@bug".

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

I have a also solution utilizing the following function:

```
const shouldSkipTest = () => { 
const testName = expect.getState().currentTestName; 
return testName?.includes('@bug'); 
};
```

However, I aim to implement a global approach (a common script) to simultaneously run all tests without having to insert this check into each test individually.
This is particularly advantageous given the high volume of tests.

Also using jest.skip() - not work due to

```
TypeError: jest.skip is not a function
```